# How to concatenate multiple videos to form a single video using ffmpeg

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg

Really good post so far, I want to ask few questions.

1. How to concatenate multiple videos to form a single video?
2. How to loop the video until the audio has not stopped?

Note: I have a different audio and video files.

Comment: Information about your inputs is required. Please include the complete console output of: `ffmpeg -i input0 -i input1`

Answer (score -1):

You can only concatenate the video files which are encoded with the same codec (i.e. you cannot really concatenate mpeg4 and mpeg2 video). Some (probably most) encoders/containers are even more strict, such as the video resolution and FPS must be the same across all videos. Some encoders even require the used video encoding options to be the same across all videos.

If those variables are satisfied (for example, all your videos are taken by the same camera), then `-vcodec copy -acodec copy` would instruct ffmpeg to copy the video (and audio) streams into the output file without recoding.

If those variables are not satisfied, and you need to recode the videos, the `-sameq` option allows you to recode the videos with almost the same quality as the original video.